# Home page dont redirect to https it remain http

Tags: apache, .htaccess

All my page are redirecting to https while only home page is not redirecting to https
example

> http://www.website.com stay same while http://www.website.com/index.php
>   redirect to https://www.website.com/index.php

any idea why?

Comment: your .htaccess rules are doing something wrong, care to post it? They should be like described here https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Comment: @TigOldBitties is correct. Sounds like something to do with your `.htaccess`. Post the code from it so we can see please!